# Unable to start debugging on the web server. Could not start Asp.Net debugging

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have few url rewriting rules set up in my web.config. They are:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>

            <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)\.aspx$"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^([^=&amp;]+)=([^=&amp;]+)$"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx?{R:2}={R:3}"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)\.aspx$"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

All these works fine and I am sure about it. However when I debug the application using F5, I get the error "Unable to start debugging on the web server. Could not start Asp.Net debugging." Don't know why is this happening. If I run it in release mode using Ctrl + F5 it works out pretty well. Can anybody tell me why is this happening? If i just remove these rules and then F5 it, it works as well. I tried to google up this issue and came up with one link. But it doesn't work for me:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1649452.aspx/1

On the above link someone ask to rename the forms starting with upper case to lower case. Pretty funny! and somebody asks to change project type to use .Net framework 3.5

Answer (score 2):

Just set your start page to a page that is not beeing rewritten by the rules.

If that does not work, add some conditions to your rules to exclude script files.
You might also have a look at this question:

[Adding IIS UrlRewrite seems to break debugging on local IIS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302317/adding-iis-urlrewrite-seems-to-break-debugging-on-local-iis-server)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link "IIS 6" section

http://devtoolshed.com/content/fixing-relative-paths-c-aspnet-when-using-url-rewriting.